# In D&D, how do you calculate the attack bonus for a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack-roll

I had my first character made for me, which was a big mistake. I am making a new lvl 6 druid/3 fighter/3 , and I'm stuck on this one part.

So if I'm a drow druid/fighter with 2 short sword and 2 dagger, and one great axe, with a eldritch knight martial archetype, I'd calculate using my str?

Comment: Welcome do RPG.se! We'll do our best to help you find an answer to your question. Please take our [tour] when you get the chance to learn more about us and earn a badge!

Comment: I feel like this is probably a duplicate question, friend.  Which is fine, if it's closed for being a duplicate it'll have a big header that says "This question already has an answer here: " and a link to the question that answers it.  I'll go looking...

Comment: Can you explain exactly what information you are looking for? Are you looking for the number you add to an attack roll? Are you looking for the number a weapon itself adds to the attack roll (eg a +1 sword)? What context is the number you are looking for supposed to be used?

Comment: Does the linked question answer yours? If not, please help us out by [edit]ing your question to explain what is still confusing you. (answering the above questions by the comments is probably going to be good as well).

Comment: [the basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) Chapter 9 explains some of this. Please review that and then revise your question so that we better understand what is confusing you.